# SFML Pre-Compiled Static Libraries Gives Unresolved External Symbol Error

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to create a .dll file, including SFML static libraries. I downloaded the libs from sfml web site, i didn't compile the *s-d.lib myself. When i try to compile the dll, it gives too many unresolved external symbol errors.

In library input options page i wrote the following:

> ```
> glew.lib
> WinMM.Lib
> glew32sd.lib
> opengl32.lib
> SFML-System-s-d.lib
> SFML-Window-s-d.lib
> freetype.lib
> freetype254.lib
> ```

An example of errors is:

```
Error   34  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetAsyncKeyState@4 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::InputImpl::isKeyPressed(enum sf::Keyboard::Key)" ( isKeyPressed@InputImpl@priv@sf@@SA_NW4Key@Keyboard@3@@Z)
```

How can i solve this situation? If i should give more information please tell me.

Thanks in advance=)

Answer (score 0):

I found that graphics-s-d.lib must also be added to dependencies, which i hadn't seen in tutorials.